# Restrict IIS application to only Domain Users

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I am trying to restrict access to a website that is hosted locally on a Windows Server 2008, running IIS7.

I would like only users apart of the domain to be able to access the URL.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start IIS Manager (click Windows Start > type "**inetmgr**" > click **Run command**).
2. In IIS Manager, expand **SERVERNAME > Sites** > click on a required website > double-click **IP Address and Domain Restrictions** (under IIS group).
3. Click Add **Allow Entry**... (on the right pane) to add an IP address or
   IP address range which will be allowed to access the website. Click
   **OK**.

   *Repeat this step to add other IP addresses to the list.*
4. Once allowed IP addresses have been added, click **Edit Feature
   Settings**... and select **Deny** for **Access for unspecified clients**.
   Click **OK**.

   Now, only users with the specified IP addresses are able to access the website.